# Keycloak & Spring Boot: restrict access per user

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

Using Spring Boot and Keycloak (OAuth2) I want to restrict URIs of the form `/api/{userId}/edit` only to user with id `userId`.

I have seen several examples for configuring access to URIs depending on role, but I didn't found any info about restricting resources depending on user.

Can I get that using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter or KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using JWT, I get the user with following method:

```
private Optional<String> getCurrentUser() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

    return Optional.ofNullable(securityContext.getAuthentication()).map(authentication -> {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof Jwt) {
            Jwt jwt = (Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal();
            return jwt.getClaims().get("preferred_username").toString();
        }

        return null;
    });
}
```

I converted `/api/{userId}/edit` URLs to `/api/edit`, since I don't need `userId` as a parameter anymore.